# Multithreading and out-of-order execution

Tags: multithreading, x86, shared-memory

Assume we have a multithreaded C program (pthreads), and the (unsynchronized) shared variable accesses of the individual threads are not reordered by the compiler. Does an x86 CPU respect the order of the shared variable accesses (within a single thread), or is it possible that it reorders some memory accesses?

Comment: out-of-order/speculative scheduling execution does only exist in the microcode level (back-end). (please notify @ me as I don't check for answers manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Unsynchronized shared variable accesses are dangerous, and out-of-order is one reason for it.

The x86 keeps writes in order (within a thread), but not reads.</strike>

This can get you into trouble, if you assume the order remains. For example:
Thread A writes to x and then to y. Assuming the compiler didn't reorder it, the cpu won't reorder it (x86 won't, others might).
thread B reads y and then x. You might think that if it got y's new value, then surely you'll get x's new value as well.
Not so. The CPU may reorder thread B's reads, so y will be actually read earlier.

**EDIT**: as "Man of One Way" pointed out, in this case, x86 (but not all processors!) guarantees ordering.
I quote the Intel software developer's manual:

> Writes by a single processor are observed in the same order by all
>   processors.

This isn't true for writes by multiple processors - they may seem to be ordered differently by different processors.

However, I highly recommend not relying on it, and using use proper synchronization instead.
The synchronization primitives are implemented with atomic operations and/or barriers, which keep you safe.

Comment: Are you saying it's possible to re-order a read with another read? "thread B reads y and then x. You might think that if it got y's new value, then surely you'll get x's new value as well." I don't think this is true According to the intel manual: "Reads are not reordered with other reads". A read could be re-ordered with an older write though.

Comment: @ManofOneWay, You're right. The manual also says "Writes by a single processor are observed in the same order by all processors". My bottom line is, I think, still correct - writing correct sync-free code based on these details is next to impossible.

Comment: x86 doesn't guarantee ordering when it comes to loads and older stores, so if there is a store A and then a load B, and they refer to different memory locations, the load B could be moved before A. So fences are still needed in some cases.

Comment: A minor nitpick, which may be important: x86 guarantees ordering between writes to *the same memory location*.

Answer (score 0):

Some reorderings are possible, due to the presence of a store buffer. See e.g. https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/weakmemory/cacm.pdf

However, the reorderings are seen only with several threads, within a single thread all accesses from that thread appear to happen in order.